# Issues generating Enterprise jar for Salesforce Soap API; issue with generated WSDL XML from Salesforce

Tags: soap, compilation, wsdl, salesforce, wsc

I've recently made some databasae changes to custom objects, and I'm trying to generate a new enterprise.jar to reflect these changes. I'm following all documentation located [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_wsc.htm) for the process. I'll also note, with the exception of some new dependencies, I've followed this process before with no errors to generate the enterprise.jar file. So this is a process that has worked for my sandbox in the past, but we haven't had any structural changes to the database in a solid 5 years.

Following along with the steps is simple enough. I generate the XML file from my Salesforce login in my developer sandbox utilizing Enterprise WSDL (we clearly have Enterprise level service, just so that's established). From there, I go to the Maven repository, get force-wsc-48.0.0.jar from there (as per the current API version of my sandbox), and then download a few dependencies like rhino, ST, and antlr-runtime. I get all files together in a temp folder in my C drive and try running command:

```
java -classpath C:\temp\force-wsc-48.0.0.jar;C:\temp\rhino1_7R4\js.jar;C:\temp\ST-4.3.1.jar;\jdk\jdk1.8.0_251\lib\tools.jar;C:\temp\antlr-runtime-3.5.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc C:\temp\enterprise.wsdl C:\temp\enterprise.jar
```

Here's where the trouble begins. Once I run this, I hit the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sforce.ws.wsdl.WsdlParseException: Parse error: Found invalid XML. could not determine namespace bound to element prefix xsd (position: TEXT seen ...ration value="ACTIONCALL_DUPLICATE_INPUT_PARAM">\r\n<xsd:annotation>... @17360:17)
        at com.sforce.ws.wsdl.WsdlParser.next(WsdlParser.java:94)
        at com.sforce.ws.wsdl.Definitions.read(Definitions.java:111)
        at com.sforce.ws.wsdl.WsdlFactory.createFromInputStream(WsdlFactory.java:69)
        at com.sforce.ws.wsdl.WsdlFactory.create(WsdlFactory.java:49)
        at com.sforce.ws.codegen.Generator.generate(Generator.java:94)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.run(wsdlc.java:115)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.run(wsdlc.java:149)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.main(wsdlc.java:71)
Caused by: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Found invalid XML. could not determine namespace bound to element prefix xsd (position: TEXT seen ...ration value="ACTIONCALL_DUPLICATE_INPUT_PARAM">\r\n<xsd:annotation>... @17360:17)
        at com.sforce.ws.parser.XmlInputStream.next(XmlInputStream.java:138)
        at com.sforce.ws.wsdl.WsdlParser.next(WsdlParser.java:90)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: com.sforce.ws.parser.XmlPullParserException: could not determine namespace bound to element prefix xsd (position: TEXT seen ...ration value="ACTIONCALL_DUPLICATE_INPUT_PARAM">\r\n<xsd:annotation>... @17360:17)
        at com.sforce.ws.parser.MXParser.parseStartTag(MXParser.java:1826)
        at com.sforce.ws.parser.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1144)
        at com.sforce.ws.parser.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1111)
        at com.sforce.ws.parser.XmlInputStream.next(XmlInputStream.java:136)
        ... 8 more
```

A snipped of the XML at error line:

```
<!--
 These are the extension code to provide additional error information 
-->
<simpleType name="ExtendedErrorCode">
<restriction base="xsd:string">
<enumeration value="ACTIONCALL_DUPLICATE_INPUT_PARAM">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>
Errors with this extended error code have the following properties: severity, actionCallName, parameterName
</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
</enumeration>
<enumeration value="ACTIONCALL_DUPLICATE_OUTPUT_PARAM">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>
Errors with this extended error code have the following properties: severity, actionCallName, parameterName
</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
</enumeration>
```

Parent schema:

```
<schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
<import namespace="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"/>
```

I don't know if it's necessary, but I'll note that there's no <xsd:schema...> at all in the XML file. xsd is used before this, but only to define element string types; eg: <element name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>

If I remove xsd prefix from everything that causes the error, I'll instead get the same error, but for soap instead of xsd. XML snippet of first instance of that:

```
<!-- Soap Binding -->
<binding name="SoapBinding" type="tns:Soap">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="login">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="LoginScopeHeader"/>
<soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
```

There's no parent schema here.

Again, there is no <soap:schema...> defined in the XML. And if I remove all of the instances of using the soap prefix, I'll land on the following issue.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sforce.ws.wsdl.WsdlParseException: targetNamespace not specified in wsdl:definitions
        at com.sforce.ws.wsdl.Definitions.read(Definitions.java:115)
        at com.sforce.ws.wsdl.WsdlFactory.createFromInputStream(WsdlFactory.java:69)
        at com.sforce.ws.wsdl.WsdlFactory.create(WsdlFactory.java:49)
        at com.sforce.ws.codegen.Generator.generate(Generator.java:94)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.run(wsdlc.java:115)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.run(wsdlc.java:149)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.main(wsdlc.java:71)
```

Again, not sure if it matters, but there's no <wsdl:definitions...> in the XML file.

I don't know if this is an issue of Salesforce generating a bad XML file (the issue occurs even in sandboxes I haven't made any database changes for, including production where I have an old but working enterprise.jar), if I don't have the right force-wsc jar file, if I'm not running it through the right version of Java (1.8, if it wasn't clear, but I've tried earlier versions of java and I just get the minor.major 52 error, which means it should be 8, as far as I know).

Any help pinpointing what the issue here is would be greatly appreciated. I'm more than open to suggestions. And if it is just Salesforce giving me a bad XML file, I can open a ticket there. I just want to make sure I'm not doing something wrong before I open a ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending more time on this, and after coordinating with a co-worker who works on a different Salesforce project, we've discovered the following

1 Salesforce was absolutely giving a bad WSDL file.

2 The generation of the bad WSDL file only occurred because I was using a Firefox web browser. Using Chrome instead to access the WSDL generation fixed the issue, of all things.

So for any poor soul that comes across this issue in the future, I hope using Chrome fixes it for you as well.